# Codificar un string a Base64 con Angular14

Tags: typescript, angularjs, http, base64, cabeceras-http

estoy intentando pasar por cabecera un usuario y contraseña para la autentificacion, y que tengo que codificarlo a Base64:

```
    const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${environment.user}:${environment.pass}`).toString('base64')
  })
```

He probado con `btoa()` y `atob()` pero estan en desuso, y tambien con buffer como os muestro en el ejemplo pero no me funciona. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que están en desuso?

Comment: no están en desuso, puedes usarlo con toda confianza

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-btoa-dev

Comment: const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${environment.user}:${environment.pass}`)
      })
    };

Comment: pruebalo con eso aver si te funciona

Comment: La cosa es que la funcion btoa() me la tacha, por eso he imaginado que no se puede usar con Angular14. Como opcion en el mensaje me aparece Buffer.from()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btoa`y `atob` no están obsoletos en los navegadores sino en node, como se explica en [este issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566), usar `window.btoa` debería funcionar sin que TypeScript arroje ningún error.

También es importante tener en cuenta 2 cosas:

1. Buffer es un módulo de node, por lo tanto no existe en el navegador, en caso de que se quiera agregar se puede optar por una librería como [buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer)
2. `btoa` según [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) espera que se pasen datos en binario, no en string, por lo que hay que transformar el string antes de usarlo, como se muestra en [este ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#solution_1_%E2%80%93_escaping_the_string_before_encoding_it)